# Coarse modelling - is there a name for this?

Tags: modeling, error-bounds

I'd like to produce a model that uses very coarse inputs and produces similarly coarse outputs.

For example, if I were estimating personal sources of wealth I might say that in a given year:

```
    There is a high likelihood that I will earn a moderate salary.
    There is a trivial chance that I will get a high lottery payout.
    There is a small chance I will inherit a large amount of money.
    Therefore...
    Salary = b * m = m
    Lottery = t * b = t
    Inheritance = s * b = s
    Total = m + t + s = m
    Where the values are either big (b), moderate (m), small (s), or trivial (t).
```

This example is far from perfect but describes how I'd like the front end of the model to look.
Obviously there is quite a lot more work required at the back end to ensure that the calculations are coherent.

Is there a name for this kind of model?
Or a branch of mathematics that would be useful to draw upon?

The approach probably looks weird, and not very useful when we could just use numbers instead, but there are a few things in its favour:

- Simple to operate
- Intuitive verbal descriptions of input and output quantities
- Easier for non-mathematicians to gain insight into the reasoning and model structure
- Keeps the focus of analysis on big picture (rather than getting drawn into considering small differences that may be an artefact of input measurement error)

Comment: On the back end, would you be doing actual arithmetic (with numbers) or would you have your own "algebra" (e.g., s * b = s ... with which I am struggling a bit, as I would have guess s * b = m)?

Comment: Undecided. Ideally I'd like to reduce the arithmetic to a set of tables but even if this is achieved I'd still be looking to perform some calculations to verify that the tables are appropriate and to work out a cap for the total number of operations that can be chained.

Comment: @P.Hopkinson, if you have faced with such a case that the input parameters are too vary, Mont-carlo simulation approach would be helpful. Have you tried that?

Comment: @A.Omidi sensible suggestion and either monte carlo simulation or decision analysis would be my plan A for dealing with most of these kinds of problems. However, I've got a couple of problems that I think would benefit from a less numerical approach.

Comment: Check out the Markowitz portfolio allocation model. It adds an element that I think is essential in this kind of decisionmaking, namely a risk aversion parameter. Would you be indifferent between a 100% chance of $10 and a 10% chance of $100?

Answer (score 4):

It's not a direct (or even necessarily close) match to what you have described, but you might be interested in the [analytic hierarchy process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_hierarchy_process) (AHP). There's some math under the hood, but as I recall what the decision maker sees is just stuff along the lines of "which of these is better/more important/more terrifying" and "by how much on a 1 to 5 scale, where 1 is "pretty much a toss-up" and 5 is "absolutely this one over that one". (I'm approximating from fuzzy memories here.)

Comment: Thanks! It isn't what I was aiming for but it might be a better way to approach some of the problems.

Answer (score 3):

A (very simple) example of coarse modelling is a [Risk Assessment Matrix](https://tms-outsource.com/blog/posts/risk-assessment-matrix/).

This has a few different variations but typically the severity and likelihood of individual risks are scored on a scale of one-to-five, multiplied and the result is colour coded with a verbal description to indicate the overall threat posed by each risk.

Personally I think that standard implementation is numerically dubious but it offers an example of a verbal/numerical hybrid model that is popular in the real world.